# angular 4 update table row on click

Tags: angular

I have a material table:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="operation">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action</mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
         <button (click)="approve(row.id)" mat-button>Approve</button>
         <button (click)="decline(row.id)" mat-button>Decline</button>
       </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

I want to update table row or table page so people can view updated status immediately. Approve() sets status to 'Approve' and decline() to 'Decline'. Status column is in table. How to refresh row from DB to let user see changes online?

Comment: make the data source a observable and use the same

Comment: could you clarify a bit?